# Update marker in real time

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I need fetch the new position from json file which will be updated at  regualr   intervals in order to update it on the map without reloading the whole page repeatedly.  How can I do without using Ajax

```
                 if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                 //==add controls
                 var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
                 map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                 map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
                 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-29.870879, 30.977258),15);

                 var htmls = [];
                 var i = 0;

                 //create marker and set up infoWindow
                 function createMarker(point,ID,name) {
                 var marker = new GMarker(point);
                 GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                 marker.openInfoWindowHtml(ID+"<br/>Name: " +name);

                 });

                  return marker;
                }



            process_Data = function(doc) {
                 //parse json file
                 var jsonData = eval('(' + doc + ')');

                 // ======== Plots the markers on Google Maps============

                   for (var i=0; i<jsonData.markers.length; i++) {
                       var point = new GLatLng(jsonData.markers[i].lat, jsonData.markers[i].lng);
                        var marker = createMarker(point,jsonData.markers[i].ID,jsonData.markers[i].name);
                       map.addOverlay(marker);

                       }
                     }

                      GDownloadUrl("points.json", process_Data);

                      }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use AJAX?

Comment: Not necessarily, if it works it will be perfect

Comment: You are using the Google Maps API V2, you should upgrade to V3 as V2 is deprecated and has little over a year of guaranteed life left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var marker;

// every 10 seconds
setInterval(updateMarker,10000);

function updateMarker() {
   $.post('/path/to/server/getPosition',{}, function(json) {
      var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(json.latitude, json.longitude);
      marker.setPosition(LatLng);
   });
}
```