# live image (bus) on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just have a quick question. I have a live feed of JSON data coming from a website that describes the location (in longitude and latitude) of a bus. I want to display this bus on top of a Google Map in live time. Querying the bus API and parsing the JSON data isn't a problem, but I'm quite confused as to how to actually throw a bus image over the actual map. A quick explanation or tutorial would be amazing!

I searched stackOverflow and googled for quite a bit, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!
-Joe

Comment: I've deduced that I can accomplish this via an overlay. My question is more broad. What would be the general direction that I should follow? Should I just have javascript looping an AJAX call to get data from the API and then update the overlay on every iteration of this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for "general direction" questions but for specific programming ones. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API would refer to your bus on the map as a "marker". By default, markers are drop pins.

You'll need to be able to do a few things.

1. Draw the map at the right zoom, and create a marker for the bus' initial position. See the [Google Maps API doco](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). If you have no problems parsing JSON, this should be a snap.
2. **Turn the default marker into a bus.** Have a look at this example using a beach patrol flag at Bondi Beach... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers
3. **Update the marker position based on your data feed.** Here is an existing SO question that relates... https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738698/828858