# Map marker seen scattered on google map though the coordinates of all marker is same

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, updates, marker

I have an issue regarding map marker. We are three members A, B and C. we are walking together on a road. And we are updating their location to each other. But the marker didn't show the location of each member together, the marker are all scattered. mean the location of each member are not same.

If member A is at on correct coordinate but other two members B and C , both are far away from member A and B is also far away from member C.

I check the coordinate of each members. the map GoogleMap itself return wrong coordinates.

Sometime the location update get stuck.

**Configuring Location manager** :

```
    self.locationManagerCurrent=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManagerCurrent.delegate=self;
    self.locationManagerCurrent.distanceFilter = 1;   //didupdateloaction method will call when user moves 1 meter
    self.locationManagerCurrent.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;  //provide precise location but more battery consumer
    self.locationManagerCurrent.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;   //
    self.locationManagerCurrent.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8) {
        [self.locationManagerCurrent requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    if ([self.locationManagerCurrent respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
        [self.locationManagerCurrent setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    }
    [self.locationManagerCurrent startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManagerCurrent startUpdatingLocation];
```

**Getting location coordinates**:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *location=[locations objectAtIndex:0];

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }

    // test the age of the location measurement to determine if the measurement is cached
    // in most cases you will not want to rely on cached measurements
    //
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0) {
        return;
    }

      self.currentLatitude=[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.currentLongitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude]; }
```

***The above code help to update individual locations.***

**Update All member's marker on map**:

```
-(void)updateAssigneesMarker
{
    for (GMSMarker *marker in [_arrMarkerAsssignee mutableCopy] ){
        marker.map = nil;
        [_arrMarkerAsssignee removeAllObjects];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < [_array_assigneesDetails count]; i++)
    {

        assignees_lat=[[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
        assignees_long=[[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
        BOOL assignees_location_status=[[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user_location_status"] boolValue];

        if (assignees_location_status)
        {
            NSData *iconData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"icon_data"] options:0];
            UIImage *icon_image=[UIImage imageWithData:iconData];

            NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"u_firstname"],[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"u_lastname"]];

            if(assignees_lat!=00.000000 && assignees_long!=00.000000)
            {
                GMSMarker *marker_assignee = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                marker_assignee.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(assignees_lat, assignees_long);
                //marker_assignee.title = name;
                marker_assignee.accessibilityLabel=name;
                marker_assignee.appearAnimation=kGMSMarkerAnimationNone;
                marker_assignee.icon=icon_image;
                if([[[_array_assigneesDetails objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"user_id"] integerValue] == [app.user_id integerValue])
                {
                    marker_assignee.userData = @"Host_Marker";
                }
                [_arrMarkerAsssignee addObject:marker_assignee];
                marker_assignee.map = _view_mapView;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any solution for this.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: how to help without code. Update the question with codes you are using

Comment: @Deep3015 i updated the question. please help me

Comment: see this [javascript question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9736508/3898339) you will get some idea.  question you asked is not javascript. please update the tags in the question. so that some one could help you